# Annotation not allowed here - Intellij

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have created simple spring boot application in Intellij.

I have created Entity Class in that when i write @Id, @Column annotations it is giving error saying annotations not allowed here.

i tried so many different post from stack overflow but my problem not got resolved.

can someone please help on this.

```
package com.ajinkya.h2demo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROOM")
public class Room {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should write the entire property. (e.g) with type and name and see if it works as a whole.

Comment: You need to complete the implementation. IDE is right and giving the correct error message. Provide the variable associated with the annotation as well and the error will get disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears, because you haven't added any field below the annotations. After you add the field, the error will disappear.

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
    private int roomId;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `Column.java` in `java.persistence`package you will find this declaration

```
...
 * @since 1.0
 */ 
@Target({METHOD, FIELD}) 
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Column {
...
}
```

This indicated that `@Column` annotation can only be applied to methods and fields.

Hence in your entity class you would apply it to method or field like below

```
@Column(name = "is_active")
protected boolean active = true;
```

or

```
@Column(name = "is_active")
public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}
```